# Getting issue when converting string date format(dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm) to Date type in Type script

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

I have a string variable with different date time formats and when converting to the Date type I am getting **NaN**. from the TypeScript, not using any npm packages how to convert it properly

**My Code**
Date time format: Deutsch

```
var stringDeutschdate = "22.02.2022, 15:56" //Deutsch
var stringDeutschdate = "22.02.2022 15:56" //Dansk
```

I want to convert this to string type to Date type, with the above format

Below is the code

```
private getUtcDate(defaultDate : Date):Date {
   const now: Date = new Date(defaultDate);
   const formattedDate:string | undefined = this.locale.date.format(
      now,"yyyyMMddHHmm","UTC");
    if(formattedDate === undefined) {
        throw new Error("failed to format date");
    }
    const parsedDate: Date = new Date(formattedDate);
    return parsedDate;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code of where how're you converting it to the Date type?

Comment: Perhaps something like ***[this](https://tsplay.dev/NDJrjW)***?

Comment: Also, I believe you're getting NaN because maybe date string is not in a standard format that JavaScript's Date constructor can parse

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to define a regex. Regex means regular expression to check the value with a specific format as defined.

Create a dynamic function as you are not using any external libraries.

```
function DeutschDate(input: string): Date | null {
  const deutschRegex = /^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}),\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;
  const danskRegex = /^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;

  const deutschMatch = input.match(deutschRegex);
  const danskMatch = input.match(danskRegex);

  if (deutschMatch) {
    const [, day, month, year, hours, minutes] = deutschMatch.map(Number);
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes);
  } else if (danskMatch) {
    const [, day, month, year, hours, minutes] = danskMatch.map(Number);
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Then do this :

```
const date1 = DeutschDate(stringDeutschdate1);
const date2 = DeutschDate(stringDeutschdate2);
```

Do let me know how it goes. THanks

Comment: Thanks, Bhavy i have gone through with you code and I have implemented I will put my code aswell

Comment: Oh great, would like to see your code.

Answer (score 1):

The built–in parser is only required to parse [3 formats specified in ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse), anything else is implementation dependent. `new Date("22.02.2022, 15:56")` produces an invalid date in Safari and Firefox at least. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Consider using a library where you can parse various format timestamps by providing the format, there are plenty to choose from.

If you are confident of the format, you can parse both timestamps using something like:

```js
function parseDeutsch(s) {
  let [day, month, year, hour, min] = s.match(/\d+/g) || [];
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, min);
}

["22.02.2022, 15:56", //Deutsch
 "22.02.2022 15:56"   //Dansk
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ' => ' + parseDeutsch(s).toLocaleString()));
```

Of course you should validate the values and check that the result is a valid date, then deal with it if it isn't.

Comment: This example will not convert the date to the dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm. By the way, thank you i fixed the issue, and I will put it in the comment

Comment: @ManojPrasanna—your question was how to parse the two formats to a *Date* object, which is exactly what the above does. You can then use the *Date* to produce any timestamp format you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have addressed the issue by implementing the following solution, and I believe it will be beneficial for you as well.

```
let parsedDate: Date = new Date(formattedDate);
        if (parsedDate instanceof Date && isNaN(parsedDate.getTime())) {
            parsedDate = this.formatDateTime(formattedDate);
        }

  private formatDateTime(dateString: string): Date {
        // Split the string into date and time components
        const [datePart, timePart] = dateString.split(/[, ]+/u);

        // Split the date component into day, month, and year
        const [day, month, year] = datePart.split(/[.\-/]/u);

        // Split the time component into hour and minute
        const [hour, minute] = timePart.split(/[:.]/u);

        const parsedDate = new Date(
            parseInt(year, 10),
            parseInt(month, 10) - 1,
            parseInt(day, 10),
            parseInt(hour, 10),
            parseInt(minute, 10)
        );

        return parsedDate;
    }
```

This issue can be resolved by adjusting the DateTime format when converting for various languages such as Norka, Sevnska, Dansk, UK, and 日本語.

Comment: The test `parsedDate instanceof Date` is redundant since `new Date()` always returns a *Date* object, regardless of the value passed.